# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() multiple array

Tags: php, database, foreach

this is my code : the warning come when no data retrieve from database .. how to fix this?.. i do not know how to change for multiple array.

```
foreach ($users_id_array[$region_chart2][$country_chart2] as $key) {

                $query_diff2 = "SELECT ut_lp_marks.obj_id, object_data.title, read_event.spent_seconds, " .
                        "read_event.read_count, ut_lp_marks.status, ut_lp_marks.percentage, ut_lp_marks.u_comment FROM ut_lp_marks ".
                        "LEFT JOIN object_data ON (object_data.obj_id = ut_lp_marks.obj_id) ".
                        "LEFT JOIN read_event ON (read_event.obj_id = object_data.obj_id AND read_event.usr_id = ut_lp_marks.usr_id) ".
                        "WHERE ut_lp_marks.usr_id=$key AND object_data.type = 'crs'";


                     $result_diff2 = mysql_query($query_diff2);

                            while($rec_diffcourse2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_diff2))
                            {

                                 if ($rec_diffcourse2['status'] == 0) {

                                        $total_diffna1++;
                                    }
                                    if ($rec_diffcourse2['status'] == 1) {
                                        $total_diffinprogress1++; 
                                    }
                                    if ($rec_diffcourse2['status'] == 2) {
                                        $total_diffpassed1++;
                                    }
                                    if ($rec_diffcourse2['status'] == 3) {
                                        $total_difffailed1++;
                                    }       



                            }
                            $no_test_country++;
                    }
```

Comment: You should explain more exactly what you wanna do.
Also you haven't showed how you populated the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be written like this:

```
if (!empty($users_id_array[$region_chart2][$country_chart2])) {
    foreach ($users_id_array[$region_chart2][$country_chart2] as $key) {
```

Except you really should be using $val and not $key

The correct syntax is

foreach ($array as $key -> $val)

Comment: i got this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: Edited to correct bracket.  I assume you are using something which automatically checks for syntax errors as you type, such as Aptana ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the dimensions in the foreach: remove `[$region_chart2][$country_chart2]`

Comment: i need it as it will retrieve from that array